# Typoscript edit body by url variable

Tags: variables, typo3

I have TYPO3 (7.6.10)

I get an url variable with typoscript:

```
lib.miacategoria= COA_INT
lib.miacategoria{
  10 = TEXT
  10.stdWrap.data = GP:tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][categories]

}
```

I can edit body class:

```
page.bodyTag > 
page.bodyTagCObject = TEXT
page.bodyTagCObject.value= cat-red
page.bodyTagCObject.wrap = <body class="|">
```

How can I change the 'page.bodyTagCObject.value' by 'lib.miacategoria'?

I want something like this:

```
switch(lib.miacategoria)
{
case 1: page.bodyTag > 
    page.bodyTagCObject = TEXT
    page.bodyTagCObject.value= cat-red
    page.bodyTagCObject.wrap = <body class="|">
break;
case 2:
page.bodyTag > 
    page.bodyTagCObject = TEXT
    page.bodyTagCObject.value= cat-BLUE
    page.bodyTagCObject.wrap = <body class="|">
break;

}
```

Comment: Important: Update your TYPO3 to 7.6.16 https://typo3.org/download/. There are security fixes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditions. Try something like this.

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|overwriteDemand|categories = 1]
    page.bodyTag > 
    page.bodyTagCObject = TEXT
    page.bodyTagCObject.value= cat-red
    page.bodyTagCObject.wrap = <body class="|">
[GLOBAL]
[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|overwriteDemand|categories = 2]
    page.bodyTag > 
    page.bodyTagCObject = TEXT
    page.bodyTagCObject.value= cat-blue
    page.bodyTagCObject.wrap = <body class="|">
[GLOBAL]
```

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Conditions/Reference/Index.html#globalvar

Answer (score 0):

You can use TYPO3 Condition like below.

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|overwriteDemand|categories > 0]
 page.bodyTagCObject = TEXT
 page.bodyTagCObject.value= cat-red
 page.bodyTagCObject.wrap = <body class="|">
[global]

[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|overwriteDemand|categories > 0]
page.bodyTagCObject = TEXT
page.bodyTagCObject.value= cat-BLUE
page.bodyTagCObject.wrap = <body class="|">
[global]
```

For more Details TYPO3 Condition click here [TYPO3 Condition](http://www.pi-phi.de/19.html)